# If I use Cloudflare's "Full SSL", do I need to buy another SSL certificate for Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, https

I am using Cloudflare for both my DNS and the other features they have. But I am using Heroku as my host.

I have enabled their [free SSL beta](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2016/5/18/announcing_heroku_free_ssl_beta_and_flexible_dyno_hours), and when I browse to my site I see the `https` section is green like so:

[image]

I will be accepting credit card payments via Stripe on my site.

Do I still need to go get an SSL cert from a third-party provider, and upload it to Heroku or is the 'free full SSL' that Cloudflare provides sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (as in, not a requirement) SSL for Stripe to work. When it's properly configured, no credit card information will hit your server. That said, users care about the green lock, and they should. So as long as it shows green for you and your users, you should be fine.

More expensive SSL certificates claim their root certificates are widely accepted, some say 100%. But if your users use the most popular browsers Cloudfare's should be OK.

Comment: That was my initial feeling too, but Stripe's documentation does specify that you need SSL - https://stripe.com/docs/security/ssl

Comment: Yeah, they are very vague about it, but I guess they are right. The only case  I can imagine is that even when their JS library is served with TLS another Javascript library could be served by a man-in-the-middle and and read user input?